# How to use javascript function from external file in twig in Symfony 6

Tags: javascript, symfony, twig, webpack-encore, symfony6

I try to use function in external js file in twig template... but isn't work (

/assets/app_departments.js

```
export function test(m) { console.log(m); }
```

webpack.config.js

```
....
.addEntry('app_departments', './assets/app_departments.js')
...
```

test.twig.html

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app_departments') }}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <script>
        test('passed');
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Browser console:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: test

Comment: maybe you are missing the `import {test} from './pathtoasset.js';`? but I'm not aware if that's responsability of webpack

Comment: @DiegoD import {test} ...  in test.twig.html - error ( .... and I thought that encore_entry_script_tags would do this work

Comment: unfortunately I'm very far from twig/php/symfony/webpack since symfony v2.8 and cannot help you further because I'm missing the domain. But I'm quite sure the culprit is how to embed the import there in the twig. Probably also in terms of composition defining it once in the master twig that you are going to include in each template

Comment: Are you sure that block javascript is executed *before* the block body?

Comment: @DarkBee, yes… it lives in <head>

Comment: Due to the chunk and versioning enabled in webpack, you can not access variables outside webpack files. Please create your main.js file and import app_departments.js into it. Then include main.js into twig.

Comment: @ScorpionZZZ did you find any solution?

Comment: Maybe this page helps someone: https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/webpack-encore/multiple-entries => Seems we *need* to create a new encore entry.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    {% block javascripts %}
      {{ parent() }}
      {{ encore_entry_script_tags('app_departments') }}
      <script>
        test('passed');
      </script>
    {% endblock %}    
{% endblock %}
```